# How to persist dynamically created structures in a database (using EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a C# application where data structures are created dynamically (by the users). E.g. such a data structure can be:
Entity `Project` with fields (or properties) `Name`, `Members`, `Deadline`, ... Another entity here is `Stakeholder` with fields like `Name`, `Position`, `Role`, `Organization`, ...
I store these structures in a DB (currently in a LocalDB instance) using EF Core. So far so good.

Now, the user should be able to instantiate the entities above, which means she can create `Project` instances (e.g. with fields `My Project` as Name, `16-02-2024` as Deadline, ...
Theses instances (their properties) are stored (in the application) basically as key-value pairs.
The question is: how to store the instances in the database? The problem is there is no `Project` class so I can't create a `DBContext` with fields `DbSet<Project>` from the example.

Well, I'm stuck here... I can create a DB table `Project` using migrations but I couldn't find any way to access that table in the application: I can't fill in with data and I also can't read data from it.
Is there a way one can read/write data from/into database tables without knowing their structure in design time (only runtime)?
Or should I approach this problem somehow differently?

EF Core is not a must (as the tool to handle DB objects), but I would like to write as few as possible SQL statements manually.

Comment: The whole *premise* of EF and other `IQueryable<T>` based query providers is that they're specifically optimized for schemas known at compile time.  Just use regular queries using traditional SQL which are inherently not statically typed when dealing with entire dynamic schemas.

Comment: Thx @Servy! So using ORM is not an option and I have to build the queries (and the other CRUD operations) manually? Does EF Core support that?

Comment: It's like asking if you can mow your lawn with a pair of scissors.  Regardless of whether or not you can, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: Or look at NoSql alternatives, like MongoDb. But most of all I think that you and your users should do some information analysis and come up with solid core entities that have fixed fields. (I mean... a StakeHolder without a Name?) Then maybe a small part can be dynamic but I simply don't believe that it should be the rule. Sometimes partly EAV can't be prevented, but 100% EAV is for freaks.

Comment: And then I didn't even mention referential integrity. That's an absolute nightmare. If the data is in key-value pairs right now it must be possible into convert (the main part of) them into a decent relational model. If not, then it's basically garbage and you should run away from it.

Comment: I finally opted for using EF Core for metadata storage and SqlKata+Dapper for the custom part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create four tables for your dynamic entities and instances:

- **EntityDefinition** - Contains meta information about the entity definition like `Name`, but not the fields/properties.
- **EntityPropertyDefinition** - Contains meta information about a single property of an entity like `Name` and `Type`.
- **EntityInstance** - Contains instances of an entity.
- **EntityInstanceValue** - Contains the property values of entity instances.

The table structure can be look like this (simplified):

```
EntityDefinition
(
    Id,
    Name
)
EntityPropertyDefinition
(
    Id,
    EntityId,
    Name,
    Type
)
EntityInstance
(
    Id,
    EntityId
)
EntityInstanceValue
(
    Id,
    InstanceId,
    PropertyId,
    IntValue?,
    BoolValue?,
    InstanceIdValue?,
    StringValue?,
    FloatValue?,
    DateTime?
    ...
)
```

The values table can be implemented in different ways like one column with the serialized value of the actual value from other libraries like MessagePack. Or you could serialize the whole object and save it directly in the `EntityInstance` table, depending on your actual requirements.

Your example project instance could be stored as follow (simplified):

```
EntityDefinition(1, "Project")
EntityPropertyDefinition(1, 1, "Name", "String")
EntityPropertyDefinition(2, 1, "Deadline", "DateTime")
EntityInstance(1, 1)
EntityInstanceValue(1, 1, 1, StringValue="My Project")
EntityInstanceValue(2, 1, 2, DatetimeValue=new DateTime(2024,2,16))
```

Comment: Thanks! The idea is that I should store all the instance values in one table (EntityInstanceValue), right? Will it not cause some performance issues (while searching/querying), even if the amount of data isn't huge? Let's say we have around 30-50 entities, each having around 10 columns and 10000 rows per entity. That's 5M rows in that table.
But I will give it a try, thank you!

Comment: As I said, it depends on your requirements. You can serialize the object (with MessagePack or JSON) and save it in the `EntityInstance` table itself like `(Id, EntityId, SerializedValue)`. This way you don't have/need the `EntityInstanceValue` table anymore, but you loose the data integrity and 3NF.